AWS RDS PostgresSQL not connecting with pgadmin but Dbeaver
I am facing an issue with AWS RDS Postgres connectivity from PGAdmin/psql command/web application
Background:
Created an AWS RDS PostgresSQL database
Made it public
Created inbound rules to allow all the traffic
Able to connect with DBeaver application and able to perform all the DB operations (create database, schema and tables)
But not able to connect with any of the following:

PGAdmin
psql command
SpringBoot JPA
Python script

Getting the following exception:
port 5432 failed: could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Matching credential not found
port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host

I guess you are using a very old version of the PostgreSQL client library libpq, but since you don't provide any detail about the software you are using, hard to say.

Your first error is probably just a nuisance error.  Since the client found kerberos credentials in its environment, it tried to use them, but since the server wasn't configure do that, the attempt failed.  Then it tried again without using kerberos, and that failed too so the 2nd error message is the "real" one. But it is also truncated.  The part you truncated away would contain the key info.
